# Building dynamic selects with options from a list and I need to add .change to the last select options

Tags: jquery

I had someone help me and he came up with this, which works great. It builds 3 dynamic select filter with options from a UL.

```
$(function() {
    renderNextLevel('#something > div > div');
});

function renderNextLevel(parent) {
    $(parent).children('ul').each(function() {
        var height = $(this).parentsUntil('#something').length;
        var current = $(parent).children('ul');
        var sel = $('.sel' + height);
        if (sel.length == 0) {
            sel = $('<select />');
            sel.attr('class', 'sel' + height);
            sel.attr('id', 'sel' + height);
            $('#something').append(sel);
            fopt =  $("<option />", {
                "value"   : "",
                "text"    : "Go to...",
            }).appendTo(sel);


            var nextLevel = function(text, idx) {
                var parents = $({});
                $('#something select').each(function() {
                    if($(this).index() > idx){
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                });

                $('#something').find('li a').each(function() {
                    if ($(this).text() == text) {
                        parents = parents.add($(this).parent());
                    }
                });
                renderNextLevel(parents);
            };

            sel.change(function() {
                 nextLevel(sel.find('option:selected').text(), sel.index());
            });
        }

        $(this).children('li').each(function() {
            var opt = $('<option />');
            var link = $(this).children('a');
            var optVal = link.attr("href");
            var optText = link.text();
            if (sel.find('option[name="' + optText + '"]').length == 0) {
                sel.append(opt);
                opt.attr('value', optVal);
                opt.attr('name', optText);
                opt.text(optText);
            }
        });
    });
 }
```

I now need the last select box options to go to a URL when selected.

```
$("#something select").change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
 });
```

But it's not working. any help?

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/qjWH7/6/

Comment: can you post your complete code or show it in jsFiddle?

Comment: could you add this alert($(this).find("option:selected").val()) inside  change(function(){}) and tell me what I get

Answer (score 0):

as you are generating the select elements dynamically you should delegate the event:

```
$(document).on('change', "#something select", function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex == 2) {
        window.location = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

Comment: When I change the option on the third select nothing happens.

Comment: @KdProgramming This should work you should change the url as they are not valid http://jsfiddle.net/qjWH7/7/

Comment: I don't want the first 2 selects to go to a URL. I only want the third one to redirect.

Comment: I am getting this - TypeError: $(document).on is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$(document).on('change', "#something select", function() {

Comment: @KdProgramming on is not supported in older versions of jQuery you should upgrade the jQuery or use `live` or `delegate` instead of `on`.

Comment: This is still not working and on the third select the URL would be based on the option selected not when the third select is created. Thanks anyway